# How to put the value of src to an input then display it on the other page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post, input

I want to put the value of `i.src` into the input and then display the generated image on the other page using the post command

```
$('#create').bind('click', function(e) {
    var datapair = $sigdiv.jSignature("getData", "image");
    var i = new Image();
    i.src = "data:" + datapair[0] + "," + datapair[1];
    $('#displayarea2').empty();
    $(i).appendTo($("#displayarea2")); // append the image (SVG) to DOM.
    document.getElemenById('sig').value = i.src;  //store the value of i.src to input
    alert("done1");
});
```

then store the value here

```
 <input type="image" id="sig" name="sig" />
```

then display it on the other page using this

```
 <?php echo $_POST["sig"]; ?>
```

Am I doing this right?

this is the sample

sample 
[telexperience.net76.net/sample.html](http://telexperience.net76.net/sample.html)

the generated image must be stored in an input then be displayed on the other page using the $_POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do but you can assign whatever value you want to the input sig.

```
$("#sig").val(youvaluegoeshere);
```

Then when the form is submitted you can access that value and display. I am not sure I understand the rest of your code though.

Comment: this is the sample http://telexperience.net76.net/sample.html i want the generated image to be stored on the input then be call out on the next page and be posted as an image

Comment: You should target it like this `var src = $('#displayarea img').attr('src')` and then store this in your `$("#sig").val(src);`

Comment: how will i know if it is stored as an input value and how will i display the image on the other page after i stored it? the display on the other page is still blank but the alert triggers when i press it

Comment: The input `<input type="hidden" id="sig" name="sig" />` should be present in your html as hidden, then you set its value with the jquery code above, then when the form is submitted you can access it with your php

Comment: nice hsalama ! using inspect element i saw that the value was stored on the src of the input the only problem is how to display it on the other page. i tried using the jquery code but it displays only a blank.

Comment: On the receiving page you don't use jquery, you use php `<?php echo $_POST["sig"]; ?>
`

Comment: what it does is it post the whole data string but not the image

Comment: You don't post images in forms, you can only pass strings over to the next page in params, you need to take that string and re-construct your image somehow.

Comment: how will i be able to pass the image on the next page?

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#create').bind('click', function(e) {
        var datapair = $sigdiv.jSignature("getData", "image");
        var img = jQuery("<img src='"+"data:" + datapair[0] + "," + datapair[1];+"' />");
        jQuery("input#sig").val(jQuery(img).attr("src"));
    })
});
```

Comment: what $sigdiv.jSignature("getData", "image") returns?

Comment: i already got the solution to get the src value for the input the only problem left is how to display it on the other page and also store it on the form data

Answer (score 1):

You should just change from:

```
 <input type="image" id="sig" name="sig" />
```

to

```
 <input type="hidden" id="sig" name="sig" />
```

Notice that I changed the type from **image** to **hidden**. Some browsers do not send the value of **image type** input controls.

Keep everything else as is and it should work fine.